# Pass var between functions EXT js

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a big question, i need in my program to pass the value of a field between two function to evaluated if the new value of that field is allow, i paste the code because is easer to understand waht i pretend to do looking the code:

```
   beforeedit: 

        function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) {
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
        var hoy = new Date();

        dia = hoy.getDate(); 

        if(dia<10)
            {
                dia=String("0"+dia);

            }

        mes = hoy.getMonth();

        if(mes<10)
        {
                mes=String("0"+mes);

        }
        anio= hoy.getFullYear();
        fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
        //alert(fecha_actual);

        var mola = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
        alert(mola);

        if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
            if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
             {
            e.cancel = false; //permite
             }
            else{
                e.cancel = true; //mo permite
            }

        }  else
        {
            e.cancel = false; //permite
        }

    },

     edit:

         function editar(e, context){
         var record = context.record;
         var recordData = record.getData();

         recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
         alert(JSON.stringify(recordData));


         Ext.Ajax.request({
             url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
             method: 'POST',

             // merge row data with other params
             params: recordData
         });
     }
    }
```

Mi big problem is that i want to pass the value of ESTLOT field form beforeedit to edit funcion editar(context,e), and i dont know how i can do.

Can somebody help me to pass the var ESTLOT that is the value of a field that i obten preperly to the edit function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i paste now, the part of my app where i validate the value of a field depends of his previous value. Thanks Rixo and Jono for the help.

```
            var gridTablaConsulta = Ext.create('Ext.grid.GridPanel', {
    title:'Consulta Tabla lotes',
    id:'gridTabla',
    store: storeTabla,
    columns: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.RowNumberer'),
        {text: "NRBE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'NRBE'},
        {text: "APLIC", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'APLIC'},
        {text: "FORM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FORM'},
        {text: "VERFOR", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'VERFOR'},
        {text: "FECLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECLOT'},
        {text: "HORLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORLOT'},
        {text: "TIPPAPLO", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPPAPLO'},
        {text: "TAMPAP", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TAMPAP'},
        {text: "FECINIIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIIM'},
        {text: "FECINIOB", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECINIOB',editor:{xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "ESTLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex:'ESTLOT',editor:{xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:true}},
        {text: "TOTPAGGE", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGGE'},
        {text: "TOTPAGIM", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TOTPAGIM'},
        {text: "DESLOT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DESLOT'},
        {text: "TIPDIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TIPDIF'},
        {text: "DIADIF", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'DIADIF'},
        {text: "FECALT", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECALT'},
        {text: "FECMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'FECMOD'},
        {text: "TERMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'TERMOD'},
        {text: "HORMOD", width: 60, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'HORMOD'}
    ],
    selType: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 2
        })
    ],

    listeners: {

        beforeedit: 

            function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) {
            var grid = Ext.getCmp('gridTabla'); // or e.grid
            var hoy = new Date();
            dia = hoy.getDate();  
            if(dia<10)
                {
                    dia=String("0"+dia);

                }
            mes = hoy.getMonth();
            if(mes<10)
            {
                    mes=String("0"+mes);
            }
            anio= hoy.getFullYear();
            fecha_actual = String(anio+""+mes+""+dia);
            e.record.beforeEditESTLOT = e.record.data.ESTLOT;
            if (e.record.data.ESTLOT === '02') {
                if (e.record.data.FECMOD === fecha_actual)
                 {
                    e.cancel = false; //permite probar mañana con cambio fecha
                 }
                else{
                    e.cancel = true; //no permite
                }

            }  else
            {
                e.cancel = false; //permite
            }

        },

         edit:
             function editar(e, context){
             var record = context.record;
             var recordData = record.getData();
             recordData.Funcionalidad = 'Modificar';
             var modificado = record.modified.ESTLOT; //valores anteriores
             alert(modificado);
             //var nuevo = recordData.ESTLOT;
             var cadena = JSON.stringify(recordData);
             alert(cadena);
             var prueba = context.record.data.ESTLOT;//valores nuevos
             alert(prueba);
             if ((modificado==='06')||(modificado==='03'))
             {

                 if ((prueba==='01')||(prueba==='02')||(prueba==='03')||(prueba==='06'))
                     {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                         //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         method: 'POST',
                         // merge row data with other params
                         params: recordData
                     });
                     }
                 else
                     {

                        alert("Si el valor anterior de estado de lote es 06 o 03 solo puede pasar a valer 04 o 05");

                     }   
             }
             if ((modificado==='04')||(modificado==='05'))
             {

                 if ((prueba==='02')||(prueba==='04')||(prueba==='05')||(prueba==='06'))
                     {
                     Ext.Ajax.request({
                         //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                         method: 'POST',
                         // merge row data with other params
                         params: recordData
                     });
                     }
                 else
                     {

                        alert("Si el valor anterior de estado de lote es 04 o 05 solo puede pasar a valer 01 o 03 o en blanco");

                     }   
             }

             if(modificado==='01')
                 {
                 Ext.Ajax.request({
                     //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     method: 'POST',
                     // merge row data with other params
                     params: recordData
                 });

                 }
             if(modificado==='  ')
                 {
                 Ext.Ajax.request({
                     //url: 'http://localhost:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     url: 'http://lnxntf05:8080/MyMaver/ServletTablaLotes',
                     method: 'POST',
                     // merge row data with other params
                     params: recordData
                 });

                 }

         }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the value in a custom property in the record:

```
// in beforeedit:
e.record.beforeEditESTLOT = e.record.data.ESTLOT
```

Then, in edit:

```
// your value's in there:
alert(e.record.beforeEditESTLOT);
```

Now, there's even a simplest method. Since your record will be modified by the editor, you can find your value in the [`modified`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-property-modified) property of the record. So, until the record is [commited](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-commit) (i.e. saved using the model or store functions), you can access the previous value this way:

```
// if undefined, that means that the ESTLOT value has not been changed by the editrecord.modified.ESTLOT
alert(record.modified.ESTLOT);
```

Comment: Hi rixo, appears the next failure when i tried the first solution: "record.beforeEditESTLOT" is null or not an object.

Comment: But wiht this all is correct i think, alert(record.modified.ESTLOT); Thanks again jejej you have solved mi question, gratitude again jejeje

Comment: The last thing is that i need to catch the new value of ESTLOT (the value that i pass to my servlet)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the functions arguments

```
function editar(e, context, ESTLOT)
{
  //....rest of your operation
}
```

or

refer to a GlobalVAR

```
 Var ESTLOT;

 function editar(e, context)
 {
   //....rest of your functions 
  ESTLOT = "abcd";
 }
 function preditar(editor, e, eOpts) 
 {
  ESTLOT = "abcd";
 }
```